# Alerts are getting deleted automatically after few minutes from Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I am adding alerts using HTTP API rest call.Those alerts are getting added but after few minutes all those alerts are deleted automatically.
http://localhost:9093/api/v1/alerts  (POST)-->Able to add the alert
http://localhost:9093/api/v1/alerts  (GET)-->I can see those alert

But after some time when I am executing GET rest-call, I cannot see those alerts.
Do I need to add any thing in Prometheus configuration or alert manager configuration. So that we can stop deleting alerts automatically? Can anyone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: How did you deploy Prometheus? It's running on top of Kubernetes? If so, maybe you have sidecar containers that are reading ConfigMaps and reloading configs from them.

Comment: No it is not running on kubernetes, I have installed it on centos following the prometheus.io document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected bahavior. An alert is considered as resolved if it has not been updated/resend after a configurable timeout.

See [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/clients/)

> Clients are expected to continuously re-send alerts as long as they are still active (usually on the order of 30 seconds to 3 minutes).

The timeout is set to 5min by default and you can modify it with the `resolve_timeout` config:

```
global:
    resolve_timeout: 30m
```

Comment: Hi Michael Doubez,
Where do I need to add  resolve_timeout: 30m? Is it prometheus.yml file?

Comment: Hello,
You should set it in AlertManager? In Prometheus, the error is resolved as soon as the condition is no longer met.

Comment: It is working now. Thanks  Michael Doubez
Can you help me related to proxy setting? 
When I added the below statement in the alertmanager.yml file.
global:
http_config:
proxy_url:'http://145.0.0.1:2145' 
 And when I am trying to run alert manager then getting the below syntax error.
could not find expected ':'",

Thanks for help Michael Doubez

Comment: You are missing the leading `http://` or `https://`. It should be something like `proxy_url: http://145.0.0.1:2145`

Comment: Sorry, http is there, I missed it in the above message. After all I am getting the above error.